# Convert java class to jar and use it as external library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm currently working on a security encryption algorithms. I found a java implementation I need, so to not invent a wheel again I want to convert the algorithm class to jar and then import it as a external library in my project.

I've tried:

```
jar -cvf result.jar class.class
```

It makes a `.jar` file but once I try to use it in Intellij `File>Project Structure>Libraries>+` and after use it, it doesn't get recognized in code with it's given name (`local.java.algorithm`).

To wrap up I want to do is: `simple java class > jar > add to project as external library > use it in code`

How to make this jar recognizable by IDEA?

Comment: try" mvn package "to convert to jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a JAR file containing classes, the structure of the JAR file needs to mirror the package name structure.

For example, if you have a class called `MyClass.java` whose contents looks like this:

```
package local.java.algorithm;
// imports
public class MyClass ... {
}
```

You compile that to MyClass.class in the directory local/java/algorithm.  The structure of the JAR file then needs to be:

```
/
/local
/local/java
/local/java/algorithm
/local/java/algorithm/MyClass.class
```

I suspect that you have actually created it like this:

```
/
/MyClass.class
```

which will mean that Intellij (or `javac` or anything else) won't be able to resolve

```
import local.java.algorithm.MyClass;
```

at compile time OR at runtime.

Comment: I'm using windows and I should specify the path that starts from src right?

Comment: You should specify a path that gives you the structure above.  Since I don't know exactly how you have your files organized on disk, I can't give you exact instructions.  But you should be able to figure it out.  Hint: `jar tvf result.jar` will show you the structure of the JAR file.